# Would you do me the honor of telling me my name?

Tags: riddle

In good company, I'm a sign of respect 
Alone, I don't denote man kind 
I was the chosen one, by George! 
There are times my presence is warranted 
And I'll usually show up if you're a good sport about it 
Would you do me the honor of telling me my name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your name is

> Mister

In good company, I'm a sign of respect

> It's respectful to address someone as Mr. Soandso. ("In good company" means alongside a name I guess)

Alone, I don't denote man kind

> <strike>Not so sure here... maybe the fact that "mister" by itself can mean a water sprayer instead of a man?</strike> "'Mister' by itself is kind of an insult. 'Now you listen here, mister!' So the idea is that you would call an unkind man 'mister' but not 'mister Smith' or something" -corsiKa

I was the chosen one, by George!

> George Washington decided on the formal address of "Mr. President"

There are times my presence is warranted

> Warrant Officers are addressed "Mr." ... <strike>and there's a song "Mr. Rainmaker" by the band Warrant. In a less warrant-centric sense, it is common to use "Mr. Lastname" when you don't know someone's first name.</strike>

And I'll usually show up if you're a good sport about it

> <strike>Misters (i.e. water sprayers) are often used to cool down athletes</strike> "think of Mr. Hockey, a lot of sports nicknames have mister in them" -corsiKa

Would you do me the honor of telling me my name?

> Mr. Mister! :P (Also titles like "mister" are known as *honor*ifics. Thanks corsiKa!)

Comment: You are correct! "In good company" does mean alongside a name! The second clue is that "Mister" by itself is kind of an insult. "Now you listen here, mister!" So the idea is that you would call an unkind man "mister" but not "mister Smith" or something. George Washington choosing Mr. is correct, as is the reference to Warrant officers. And for athletes, think of Mr. Hockey, a lot of sports nicknames have mister in them. For the last clue, 'honor' is a reference to 'honorific' which is ... what "mister" is. Well done!

Comment: @corsiKa Ahh I get it. For the second one when I think "mister" alone, I imagine a little kid addressing a stranger "hey, mister?" and I couldn't make it work so I thought it might be a pun on the multiple meanings (which helped me get the wrong answer to the sports clue too lol)

Comment: I have to admit, while incorrect, incorporating "mister" in that definition is super clever! I wish I could say it was what I was thinking!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's...

> Honesty?

In good company, I'm a sign of respect

> Honesty could be considered a sign of respect...to the right people, that is

Alone, I don't denote man kind

> Mankind is known for its skill at lying

I was the chosen one, by George!

> George Washington [is known for his supposed extreme honesty](http://www.infoplease.com/t/history/true-washington/honesty.html)

There are times my presence is warranted

> Honesty isn't *always* the best policy for every situation, but it is warranted at times

And I'll usually show up if you're a good sport about it

> People are more willing to be honest if you can handle the truth

Would you do me the honor of telling me my name?

> Honesty?

Comment: I like your response to the second clue, except it references "mankind" not "man kind".

Comment: I though the saying was honest Abe....? (But then again I'm not American :} )

Comment: @Markn George Washington has a fable about cutting down a cherry tree and not lying about it

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> democracy or freedom

In good company, I'm a sign of respect

> Many developed countries consider democracy important and sign of progress

Alone, I don't denote man kind

> Not every country has democracy

I was the chosen one, by George!

> George Washington chose democracy over other systems for USA

There are times my presence is warranted

> Sometimes freedom is limited for specific reasons

And I'll usually show up if you're a good sport about it

> Countries on a good rapport with public are usually democracies

Would you do me the honor of telling me my name?

> democracy

Answer (score 2):

Second attempt:=============================================================

In good company, I'm a sign of respect

> "Company" in this case might refer to more than just a \$2 bill. The more money you have, generally the more respect you have.

Alone, I don't denote man kind

> If you have nothing but a $2 bill, you still have a note. Thus, you are not denoted.

I was the chosen one, by George!

> Washington chose four members for his presidential cabinet:  Secretary of State Thomas Jefferson, Secretary of Treasury Alexander Hamilton, Secretary of War Henry Knox, and Attorney General Edmund Randolph.

There are times my presence is warranted

> Sometimes you need to pay for things with money.

And I'll usually show up if you're a good sport about it

> If you're a good sport and keep looking, maybe you'll find a $2 bill.

Would you do me the honor of telling me my name?

> Thomas Jefferson, as pictured on the $2 bill.

First attempt:===============================================================

I'm probably way off, but here goes...

> Is your name force?

In good company, I'm a sign of respect

> Others often respect a show of force

Alone, I don't denote man kind

> A force of nature is a phenomenon that humans cannot control.

I was the chosen one, by George!

> "You were the chosen one!" might be a reference to Star Wars: Episode 3 in which characters use the force. It was also directed by *George* Lucas. Could also refer to George Washington who won American independence by use of force.

There are times my presence is warranted

> Force is sometimes warranted.

And I'll usually show up if you're a good sport about it

> If you play by society's rules, you'll usually be able to call up the police (or whoever) to resolve situations by force.

Would you do me the honor of telling me my name?

> Force?

Comment: The George is indeed George Washington, but for a very very different reason.

Comment: The denote interpretation is very nice, but as referenced on AstroCB's, that clue is "man kind".

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking

> Lady

In good company, I'm a sign of respect

> Lady is a term of respect

Alone, I don't denote man kind

> Ladies are not men, they're women

I was the chosen one, by George!

> George Washington chose his wife Martha, the First Lady

There are times my presence is warranted

> The use of Lady as a title is appropriate when given certain royal honours (By royal warrant)

And I'll usually show up if you're a good sport about it

> Not sure about this one

Would you do me the honor of telling me my name?

> Lady is an honorific

Comment: Your response to the fourth clue is actually very useful for a different clue, for a different reason obviously.

Answer (score 2):

In good company I am a sign of respect...

> Hand Shake.

Alone, I don't denote man kind....

> part of the human body.

I was the chosen one, by George....

> in Washington's inaugural address the hand in referenced 'on one hand' and 'on the other hand'.

There are times my presence is warranted....

> writing, grasping, grabbing, slapping, etc.

And I usually show up if your a good sport about it....

> high five hand slap.

My name is

> Hand.

Comment: That was my thought as well when I read the question just now. I'm not a native English speaker, so I wasn't sure about the "man kind" clue. I thought it could mean that the hand alone doesn't determine if "man" or "woman"!?

Comment: Ooo I like it! Also for the second clue, "alone" wouldn't denote "mankind" because we have two hands, not one! It's not correct, but it's very elegant!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is

> Command?

In good company, I'm a sign of respect

> People in command are hopefully respected.

Alone, I don't denote man kind

> Commanding man is not necessarily a kind thing to do.

I was the chosen one, by George!

> George Washington was chosen to be the Commander in Chief.

There are times my presence is warranted

> Command is sometimes necessary, especially to govern large groups.

And I'll usually show up if you're a good sport about it

> If there are those willing, a leader tends to command others.

Would you do me the honor of telling me my name?

> Ummm.... I dunno.

It's all a little far out from the phrasing of the riddle as a whole though and it doesn't obviously match up with all the extra clues you gave so I dunno....

Comment: It's incorrect, but you get points for realizing the last line is actually a clue as opposed to just a question to finish off the riddle!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be

> Foreman?

*In good company, I'm a sign of respect*

> A foreman is somebody to be respected.

*Alone, I don't denote man kind*

> A single foreman (or four men perhaps?) isn't the whole of mankind.

*I was the chosen one, by George!*

> George Foreman is a retired boxer, formerly World Heavyweight Champion.

*There are times my presence is warranted

And I'll usually show up if you're a good sport about it*

> Boxing is a sport?

*Would you do me the honor of telling me my name?*

> (George) Foreman?

Comment: This is really cool, I've had a lot of folks at work name a lot of georges but this one never came up. Sadly this is not the answer, and fails to account for the 4th and 6th lines uniquely.

Comment: Now that it's solved, I'll be honest and say this was my favorite interpetation. Especially the "four men" thought line. That was clever!

Answer (score 1):

Thought of this:

> Armstrong

and tried to shoehorn it in...

In good company, I'm a sign of respect

> I can't think of anything for this.

Alone, I don't denote man kind

> Neil Armstrong on his own only took "one small step for man", but with the world looking on he took "one giant leap for mankind"

I was the chosen one, by George!

> George Armstrong Custer, often portrayed as arrogant probably thought he was the chosen one when it came to dealing with the native Americans,

There are times my presence is warranted

> The "strong arm" of the law might have a warrant to access a premesis.

And I'll usually show up if you're a good sport about it

> Lance Armstrong would be very happy for you to be a good sport, but he would be anything but!

Would you do me the honor of telling me my name?

> Armstrong

Comment: You really had to strong arm some of those clues! An admirable attempt, but sadly this is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know the Answer

> Mr. President.

In good company, I'm a sign of respect

> the president, in any company worth mentioning, is respected

Alone, I don't denote man kind

> No thoughts here.

I was the chosen one, by George!

> When he was elected president, there was no title for the position.
> "Washington consented to the demands of James Madison and the United States House of Representatives that the title be altered to 'Mr. President.'" source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._President_%28title%29)

There are times my presence is warranted

> The same reason @wossman stated.

And I'll usually show up if you're a good sport about it

> well... No thoughts.

Would you do me the honor of telling me my name?

> Mr. President

Comment: You are nearly correct, you took a correct clue too far. But very close!

Answer (score 1):

In good company, I'm a sign of respect

> If an army is fighting for your benefit and safety, respect is usually returned

Alone, I don't denote man kind

> An army without a strong government can be out of control

I was the chosen one, by George!

> George Washington led an army

There are times my presence is warranted

> In times of disorder or conflict, an army may be needed

And I'll usually show up if you're a good sport about it

> If you're a good ally, an army may be sent for support

Would you do me the honor of telling me my name?

> An army

Answer (score 1):

Your name is:

> Condom

---

In good company, I'm a sign of respect

> Show her your respect by being prepared

Alone, I don't denote man kind

> Certainly not, although maybe just the "man"

I was the chosen one, by George!

> George was a smart fellow

There are times my presence is warranted

> If you're not trying to have a baby

And I'll usually show up if you're a good sport about it

> If you do what she asks you'll get a chance to use it

Comment: I.. I don't even... But you left off the last clue!

Answer (score -1):

> Curiosity

In good company, I'm a sign of respect

> Curiosity shows that you wish to learn more about a subject say in a class, curiosity makes you ask questoins which

Alone, I don't denote man kind

> Curiosity results in questions and that needs to be answered which cannot be done if you are alone.

I was the chosen one, by George!

> Curios George

There are times my presence is warranted

> Say, when you are learning a new topic,  curiosity furthers your knowledge.

And I'll usually show up if you're a good sport about it

> If you sow interest in a topic , your curiosity arises.

Would you do me the honor of telling me my name?

> Curiosity